# How to put a java class in a Object and use it methods

Tags: java

It is easy to put a class into a Object. But when I try to perform methods on it at Line 36:
`aClass.getInfo(3);`
 I get a  `cannot find symbol` and cannot compile. How could I use a class in a Object? The aim is to use either classA or classB, depending on an int or something else.

```
package testit;

public class TestIt {

    Object aClass;

    public interface InFace {

        void getInfo(int i);
    }

    public class ClassA implements InFace {

        @Override
        public void getInfo(int i) {
        System.out.println("ClassA: " + this.getClass() + " " + i);
        }
    }

    public class ClassB implements InFace {

        @Override
        public void getInfo(int i) {
        System.out.println("ClassB: " + this.getClass() + " " + i);
        }
    }

    public void testClass() {
        ClassA testA = new ClassA();
        ClassB testB = new ClassB();
        testA.getInfo(1);
        testB.getInfo(2);
        int i = 1;
        if (i == 1) {
            aClass = testA;
        } else {
            aClass = testB;
        }

        System.out.println("aClass: " + aClass.getClass());

//        aClass.getInfo(3);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestIt test = new TestIt();
        test.testClass();
    }
}
```

Comment: Btw the reason you can't do `aClass.getInfo(3)` is: what if `aClass` holds a `String`? `String`s don't have a `getInfo` method.

Answer (score 1):

Since `aClass` will hold only `ClassA` or `ClassB`, which are both subtypes of `InFace`, you can change

```
Object aClass;
```

to

```
InFace aClass;
```

Then, your variable of type `InFace` will support a method, called `getInfo(int i)` and your code will compile.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `InFace` to declare your `Object aClass;`, because both of your classes implements that interface:

`InFace aClass;`